# Why does PrintStream print to console

Tags: java

How come that `System.out.println("Hello World")` prints to console?

`out` is a static variable of type `PrintStream`. On out you call `println()`. How come it prints to console? Is that a default channel? Could I also say print to a file ?

Comment: Here is a solutin: https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file
But is it java? You are sure ? It looks like C++

Comment: Yes, System.out == console.

Comment: You could probably reassign the out by using `System.setOut(PrintStream out)` provided that the SecurityManager for your JVM allows this. Typically writing to a file is done differently, like Bartosz said.

Comment: `PrintStream` wraps an `OutputStream`. And stdout is an ostream/`OutputStream`

Comment: System.out represents stdout "Stdout, also known as standard output, is the default file descriptor where a process can write output." https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=java.lang.System.Logger

Comment: Since Java 9, the standard way of logging your log statements to a file is by using System.Logger - https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.Logger.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The console is the default output stream. In order to write to file using the system.out.println() command you need to change the output stream.

```
PrintStream fileOut = new PrintStream("./out.txt");
System.setOut(fileOut);
System.out.println("this write in file");
```

Comment: Ok. so variable out is from Type PrintStream  . I thought PrintStream is only for Files . So how can it be default to console. Console is not a file.

Comment: No, PrintStream is not only for the file. PrintStream adds few functionalities to its super class, OutputStream. There is Another OutputStream called FileOutputStream which is made for files. To create a PrintStream that can write to files you need to do something like this:

new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Engineer.txt"));

Answer (score 0):

`out` is instantiated during startup and gets mapped to the standard output console of the host (which is the console by default).

You can change the `out` object, e.g. instead of standard output to write to a file, using the `setOut` method:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("log.txt")));
System.out.println("Writing to log.txt");
```